# Evolution of an application, data treatment, and synchronization

Tags: java, android, performance, web-services

I m actually an android developper in a little society in France. I ve never been faced to this problem before now.

Explanation :

- We have developped an android application which has to work with and without network connection (impliying synchronization ascending and descending)
- The user has to connect himself, then we request the WebService to access the informations he needs to make his treatments. But, he needs to get ~2500 lines (marshalled by JackSon in our objects). This synchronization takes nearly 3 mns in 3g and more than 5 mns in Edge... and then make what he had to do, and sent the information back to the server when he get a network connection.

MySQL and our webservices give information in good time ( ~0.05s/requests for mysql, and ~105ms/request accessing the webservice from a webpage). We actually need 10-15 requests to get all the needed informations.

Is there any way to reduce, or a solution to improve / refactor our coding methods.

In fact, I guess we didnt think the application by the good side, when I look Google drive mobile or messenger Facebook app which are really really fast x__x' .

So I m looking for a solution, and moreover, we have a client that needs to get ~50 000 lines per users in the next few monthes...

Thanks for all,

Comment: What does the reader do with the 2500 lines? Read them? This might take a few hours, so they can wait 3 minutes. :D But seriously, are you suggesting that you're sending too much data? It looks like this, however, without any details it's hard to say what to leave out.

Comment: The user gets a list of zones to visit (from 1 to 500) (like in a museum), in these zones, he has to check some informations (what he likes, what he dislikes, what the museum should improve, he cans comment, fill some informations etc...), he can take pictures, etc...

Comment: Is it that necessary to download information all at once, you can can gradually download the information and based on downloaded information you can show loading info or any other ui updates accordingly

Comment: Can you download complete textual vocabulary of objects just once - when the device is connected via WiFi, and then use (short) object IDs during synchronization?

Comment: It s necessary to download all the information at login( the only moment that we are sure there is a network connection, assuming the contract). Concerning the use of short object ID during sync, it's not possible... how to get full information when needed, when the only real variable is the network :/